# Can't build game because of ObjectNames.GetUniqueName, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I'm building my game and after like 4 seconds there is an error that says:
`Assets\PlayerInventory.cs(228,37): error CS0103: The name 'ObjectNames' does not exist in the current context` I'm using the function so that the objects don't all have the same name, but I can't build because of it. I'm using it like this:

`string uniqueName = ObjectNames.GetUniqueName(names, "");`
this is just adding a number on the end so it would be

```
Object
Object (1)
Object (2)

and so on...
```

Why is it not letting me build?

EDIT:

Code snippet:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerInventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Names taken
    public string[] names = new string[] { "Object" };
    
    void Start()
    {
         string uniqueName = ObjectNames.GetUniqueName(names, "");
    }
}
```

Some of the `using` are not needed for this snippet.

Comment: Did you include ```using UnityEditor```?

Comment: Yes, i have that up the top. EDIT: It works in game, but not when building

Comment: Could you share the code snippet then?

Comment: Added a snippet of what is needed

Comment: Ok, just tested it and there seems to be no problem. What platform are you building for?

Comment: PC, would there be an issue with anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`ObjectNames`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ObjectNames.html) is part of the namespace [`UnityEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UnityEditor.html) which only exists within the Unity editor itself and is completely stripped of during the build process.

=> You can't use any of it in the actual released application, it is only for doing stuff within the editor itself.

---

Unfortunately the exact content of `GetUniqueName` is also not public in the [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/ObjectNames.cs) but you can implement something similar yourself.

There might be better and more efficient ways but I would go with e.g.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    // Regex Matches a trailing indexer 
    // e.g. "Example (1)"
    private const string k_IndexMatch = " \\(([0-9]+)\\)$";

    private static bool HasIndexer(string name, out int? index, out string nameWithoutIndex)
    {
        var matches = Regex.Matches(name, k_IndexMatch);

        var nameIndexMatch = matches.LastOrDefault();
        // or in case of older Unity/c# version without Linq
        //var nameIndexMatch = matches.Count == 0 ? null : matches[matches.Count - 1]; 

        if (nameIndexMatch == null)
        {
            index = null;
            nameWithoutIndex = name;
            return false;
        }

        // First group is always entire match, we want only the numeric value which is the second group
        var group = nameIndexMatch.Groups[1];
        index = int.Parse(group.Value);
        nameWithoutIndex = name.Substring(0, name.Length - nameIndexMatch.Value.Length);

        return true;
    }

    public static string GetUniqueName(this string name, IEnumerable<string> existingNames)
    {
        HasIndexer(name, out var index, out var nameWithoutIndex);

        foreach (var existingName in existingNames)
        {
            if (existingName == nameWithoutIndex)
            {
                // Exact match (without index) 
                // in this case either keep your index or if there is none use 1
                if (index == null)
                {
                    index = 1;
                }

                continue;
            }

            if (HasIndexer(existingName, out var existingIndex, out var existingNameWithoutIndex))
            {
                if (existingNameWithoutIndex == nameWithoutIndex)
                {
                    index = index == null ? existingIndex + 1 : Math.Max(index.Value, existingIndex.Value + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        return nameWithoutIndex + (index == null ? "" : $" ({index})");
    }
}
```

See also [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/91GVVe) ([older c#](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J1YKNT))

Example usage

```
var uniqueName = "Example".GetUniqueName(new []{"Example 0", "Example (1)", "Nope", "Example", "Example (2)"});
```

=>

```
Example (3)
```

since only `"Example (1)", "Example", "Example (2)"` are overlapping matches and highest free index is `3`.

Comment: Aha it seems you answer all of my posts! How would I implement this into my project? Like how would it slot into my project?

Comment: what `using` needs to be at the top of my project?

Comment: @Jerry mainly `using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` I guess

Comment: I get this error: `Assets\StringExtensions.cs(16,64): error CS1061: 'MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'LastOrDefault' and no accessible extension method 'LastOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: you added `using System.Linq;` ? [`LastOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault) is part of that which btw you can find out by [googling it ...](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+LastOrDefault) ;) .. but to make it easy those are the ones I have `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Comment: I still have the error as before even with your usings that you have put at the bottom of your comment

Comment: hmmm what Unity/c# version is that? Works just fine for me tbh

Comment: Unity 2019.4.19, Visual Studio 2019

Comment: hm upgrading Unity version an option for you? In general you should try and keep up with the latest LTS (currently `2021.3.16`) - or a least push the minor version (latest 2019 was `2019.4.40`) - anyhow .. indeed I think 2019.4 still uses an older c# version so you will have to do that manually, I'll update the code

Comment: Unfortunately updating Visual studio or Unity is not an option for me as I'm on a school computer

Comment: @Jerry visual studio wouldn't help much ;) It is only the IDE but the code is compiled by Unity. Tell your school to keep up to date then ... 2019 is 3 years old ^^ There are already two new major LTS versions after that